Should I use route.js file in next.js 14 for rendering UI, or just collect data
Problem is that I can not decide, either I can not find material to know if I should render UI inside route.js file or to call those data from route and render in different page.js file
I have this code on route.js file:
route.js file

Looks fine how you have it, visual elements should come from page.js and api calls from route.js
